# How can I turn on Adventure Sync?

Tags: pokemon-go, ios

Maybe this question fits better into https://apple.stackexchange.com/, but it will probably help more people in this area:

I have iOS 13 and the newest version of Pokemon Go installed and when I try to turn on Adventure Sync in Pokemon Go's settings, following popup window appears:

[image: pokemon go adv sync pop up window]

The screenshot is in German, but it says following:

> **Missing Adventure Sync permissions**
>
> Pokémon GO needs your location in order to find nearby Pokémon and PokéStops. Please adapt your settings and activate location services.
>
> 1. Open Health App.
> 2. Select "sources".
> 3. Select "Pokémon GO".
> 4. Select "Turn on every category".

(Just a corresponding translation, not certain of the correct English wording)

In the iOS settings I granted Pokémon GO any permission I am able to.
However, in the Health App I can't find any entry for Pokémon GO at all ...

What do I have to do to turn on Adventure Sync successfully on iOS 13+?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have iOS 13 but I did set this up before I updated my phone so I'm not sure if I was just grandfathered in.  Try the following in the Health app:

1. Hit the icon in the top right corner to go to your account.
2. Under the privacy section hit apps.
3. You should see Pokemon GO there.

[image: Picture of Apps in Health application on iOS 13]

Then just allow access to everything as suggested in the instructions from Pokemon GO.

EDIT:

Per the conversation in the comments, follow the directions in this Reddit thread https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/c58uo5/adventure_sync_on_ios_13_possible/ to fix this issue in iOS13 if the above did not work:

1. Turn off automatic app download under General in the watch app (if you have an apple watch).
2. Reinstall Pokemon GO.

Comment: I assumed Pokemon GO to be in this section. However, for me it doesn't appear there.

Comment: It could be an issue on either side to be honest.  I'd wait for a Pokemon GO update and try again since we all know Apple does not like to patch their apps in a timely manner!

Comment: True. And going back to iOS 12 is not possible afaik. At least not on an easy way. I setup Pokemon GO right after I have installed the iOS update. Bad luck probably :D

Comment: You should also check in the iOS settings app since there are also app allowance settings under Settings -> Health -> Data Access & Devices.  Hopefully that will help.

Comment: Also looked through all of those settings. Unfortunately No Pokemon GO there.

Comment: I turned on adventure sync as soon as it was added as a feature.  Per this thread, https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/c58uo5/adventure_sync_on_ios_13_possible/, try reinstalling the Pokemon GO (this was during the beta of iOS13).

Comment: Apple Watch is mentioned there. What exactly does he mean? Do you know?

Comment: There is a setting in the watch app that will automatically download apps from your iPhone to the Apple Watch if there is a corresponding watch app.  If you have an Apple Watch, it is under General right at the top Automatic App Install.  It is implied that you have to turn that off then reinstall Pokemon GO.

Comment: going to try this, however there is no watchOS app for Pokemon GO. might have some effect though. If that doesn't work. I will try to remove the watch completely.

Comment: It worked !!! Thank you. This really did the job.

Comment: There is a watchOS app for Pokemon GO.  It is pretty useless tbh.  It will just tell you if there is a pokemon/pokestop in range so you don't have to have the app open on your phone.  It was made that way to not directly compete with their wearable the Pokemon GO Plus, which will buzz if a Pokemon is nearby and you can press the button on it to attempt to catch it.

Comment: but it is a third party app for the watchOS and not pokemon go directly? Because I dont find a Pokemon Go watch App ...

Answer (score 7):

If Pokémon Go is not listed under the Health options in your settings, you have a couple of different options to try based on a few sources:

1. Niantic Support [suggests](https://twitter.com/NianticHelp/status/1142204597517398018) to check your Motion & Fitness configuration within your Privacy settings.

   > It might be possible that Fitness Tracking is not permitted on your device, hence you're unable to view Pokémon GO in the Apple Health app. Try enabling it from the Motion & Fitness option under 'Privacy Settings'.
2. If the the problem persists after checking your privacy settings, the [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/a0a5qf/pok%C3%A9mon_go_doesnt_show_up_in_health_app_sources/) community suggests un-installing and re-installing Pokémon Go. Many of the users there confirm this fixed this issue for them.

If neither of the above worked, then I suggest [submitting a support ticket](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?p=web&contact=1) to Niantic

Comment: 1. probably relates to Android and not iOS.
2. I have seen this post, too. But it didn't work for me.

I think that it has to do with the new Health Update from iOS 13, but couldn't find any statement, that proves this assumption

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 For the twitter post, the user who posted the question on the support page stated they were using iPhone SE. I have iOS13 as well and I haven't had any problems with Adventure Sync

Comment: Ok eventually managed to find those settings, but still no Pokemon GO is listed there. Did you have set it up with iOS 12 already?

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 Android doesn't have an "Apple Health" app, only iOS devices do.